# Sharing a single database helper object in my application

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have a question related to database helper in ormlite

I have database helper and on every activity I create a new instance with the current context like this.

```
DatabaseHelper     helper  = new DatabaseHelper(this);
Dao<User, Integer> userDao = null;
try {
    userDao = helper.getUserDao();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What if I only created a single object of database helper in application class and get it using getApplicationContext method? application will only have a single helper object

Is it right way to do this?

Comment: If you only build one instance to shared it across every activity, yes you will have only one helper. Not sur why you are doubting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should always use a single instance of the DatabaseHelper throughout the app.

Comment: would you care to explain why?

Comment: You can use the same instance of the DatabaseHelper throughout the app, this prevents unnecessary creation of objects which consume memory. Accessing it from one place also helps in testing the app, which would be difficult otherwise.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details about why.  The contents of your comment should go into the answer.